# How to loop through a specific column in each row for a range object VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How to loop through range object for each row for a specific column. For instance, if range object is `A1:D5` I want to loop through `A4, B4, C4, D4` values.

When I try

```
Set ranges = Application.InputBox(Title:="Select the Range", Type:=8)

For Each r In ranges.Rows
    Msgbox r(1,4) 
Next r
```

It trows me an error.

Comment: I believe for "For each statement to work", r must be an element of an array/colllection. So in your case, r has to be defined as a cell and use "For each r in ranges"

Comment: Try `MsgBox r.Cells(1, 4)`

Comment: You also must define the `Prompt` parameter in the `InputBox` function (it is not optional). `Set ranges = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the range", Title:="Select the Range", Type:=8)`

Answer (score 0):

Try below codes

```
Sub Loop4Row()
Dim r As Long, Ranges As Range

Set Ranges = Application.InputBox("Select the Range", Type:=8)
    For r = Application.Min(Ranges.Column) To Application.Max(Ranges.Columns)
        MsgBox Cells(4, r)
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont want to go through all cells inside. just column D

Comment: Did you try my code? It only loops columns not all cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Edit: Added condition for displaying cells on 4th row.

```
Set Ranges = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the Range", Title:="Select the Range", Type:=8)

For Each r In Ranges
  If r.Row = 4 Then
    MsgBox r.Value
  End If
Next r
```

Comment: OP wants to loop through the 4th column only. I believe it should change to `For Each r In Ranges.Columns(4).Cells`

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through Cells of a Row

**Short**

```
Dim r as Range
For Each r In ranges.Rows(4).Cells
    Msgbox r.Address, r.Value
Next r

' or 

Dim r As Range, rg As Range
Set rg = ranges.Rows(4)
For Each r in rg.Cells
    Msgbox r.Address, r.Value
Next r
```

**Long**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughTheFourthRow()
    
    Const sTitle As String = "Loop Through the Fourth Row"
    Const sRow As Long = 4
    
    ' Determine the parameter of the 'Default' argument.
    Dim dAddress As String
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        dAddress = Selection.Address
    Else
        dAddress = "$A$1"
    End If
     
    ' Input.
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim srg As Variant
    Set srg = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a range", _
        Title:=sTitle, Default:=dAddress, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Validate input (Canceled?).
    If TypeName(srg) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation, sTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Validate input (too few rows).
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < sRow Then
        MsgBox "There are only " & srCount & " rows in the range.", _
            vbExclamation, sTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Debug.Print srg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' Loop through the cells of the one-row range.
    Dim sCell As Range
    For Each sCell In srg.Rows(sRow).Cells
        Debug.Print sCell.Address(0, 0), sCell.Value
    Next sCell

End Sub
```